# How to resize div element less than its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and there is a TreeView in a cell. Here is my code:

```
   <style>
        #leftPanel
        {
            width:60px;
            height:'100%';
            border:1px solid red;
            background:yellow;
        }  
    <style>

        <table>
         <tr>
          <td> 
           <div id="leftPanel">
             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="TreeView" />
             <%-- Here is a TreeView --%>
           </div>
          </td>
         </tr>
          <%-- other code --%>
        <table>

 $(function () {
         $('#leftPanel').resizable(
         {
             handles: 'e, w'
         });
     });
```

I can't reduce the size of my div less then the size of my TreeView. 
What code need I write to allow leftPanel to be less than the size of TreeView ? It is necessary if TreeView node's text too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property for the div in CSS.

Set it to `overflow: auto;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yApg9/)

Comment: As @sachleen said, you have to use the overflow property. If you specify overflow: hidden the content will be hidden (no scollbar).